# Ajax post data of Multiple selected Checkboxes - Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am using laravel and have list of data in a table which has checkboxes to each.

I am looking for multiple delete operation on controller side. I tried for single delete and it worked like charm. But when I used post method for these datas it throws me 500 internal server error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

         $(function() {
             $("#btndel").click(function(){
                 var a = [];
                 var cboxes = $('input[name="suppcheck[]"]:checked');
                 var len = cboxes.length;
                 for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
                     a[i] = cboxes[i].value;
                 }
                 console.log(a);
                 var element = $(this);

                 if(confirm("Are you sure you want to group delete this?"))
                 {
                     $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         url: "groupDeleteSupp",
                         data: "ids":[{info:a}],
                         alert(data);
                         success: function(){}
                     });

                     $(this).parents(".show").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow")
                            .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
                 }

                 return false;
             });
         });   
</script>
```

here is the ajax script. The ids are fecthed perfectly in array a[].

here is my logic at controller,

```
$data = Input::all();
        //p($data);
        if(Request::ajax())
        {
            $ids = $request->input('info');

            if(isset($ids))
            {
                DB::table('supplier')->whereIn('RefAddress', $ids)->delete(); 
                DB::table('address')->whereIn('ID', $ids)->delete(); 
                Session::put('groupDelete');
                return redirect('/Suppliers');
            }
            else
            {
                Session::put('groupFail');
                return redirect('/Suppliers');
            }
        }
```

What should be done to pass those values. Its not form either hence I assumed I dont have to deal with csrf token.

Awaiting your reply.

Comment: Doesn't Session::put() require two arguments?

Comment: @MihkelAllorg yes it does...one for the session variable and one is the value to it...i wrote that code in hurry hence I missed it out.. the correct is `Session::put('some_variable','your message');`

Comment: I suggest trying to first of all find out which statement throws the error. Try `dd($data)` In the controller, start from right after initializing `$data` and then move the `dd($data)` down statement by statement until you get the 500 again.

Comment: hi,by your question my problem solved :) thank you

Comment: @masood pleasure sir :-)